# what does it mean by 'invalid command name ".!canvas"'

Tags: python

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("ping pong")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height= 600)
wn.tracer(0)



#Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0)

#Paddle B
paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_b.speed(0)
paddle_b.shape("square")
paddle_b.color("white")
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.goto(350, 0)

#Ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("white")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.dx = 2
ball.dy = 2

# Function
def paddle_a_up():
    y = paddlea.ycor()
    y += 20
    paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_a_down():
    y = paddlea.ycor()
    y -= 20
    paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_b_up():
    y = paddlea.ycor()
    y += 20
    paddle_b.sety(y)

def paddle_b_down():
    y = paddlea.ycor()
    y -= 20
    paddle_b.sety(y)

#Keyboard binding
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, "Up")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, "Down")


#Main game loop
while True:
    wn.update()

    #move the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() +ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    #Border checking
    if  ball.ycor() > 290:
        ball.sety(290)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if  ball.ycor() < -290:
        ball.sety(-290)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.xcor() > 390:
        ball.goto(0,0)
        ball.dx *= -1

    if ball.xcor() < -390:
        ball.goto(0,0)
        ball.dx *= -1

    #Paddle and ball collisions
    if (ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.xcor() < 350) and 
(ball.ycor() <
paddle_b.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > paddle_b.ycor() -40):
        ball.setx(340)
        ball.dx *= -1

    if (ball.xcor() < -340 and ball.xcor() > -350) and 
 (ball.ycor() <
  paddle_a.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > paddle_a.ycor() -40):
        ball.setx(-340)
        ball.dx *= -1
```

I am unable to move paddle b completely it allows me to move paddle b up or down by only 5 pixels and how should I change the speed of the ball which is too fast. I am using the community version of visual studio 2019. as soon as I end the process it takes me to the ball part of the code displays  'invalid command name ".!canvas"'

Comment: sure you're not supposed to use ```paddle_a```?   you have ```paddlea``` which isn't defined. (at least not in the code you provided)

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Are you asking about "'invalid command name “.!canvas”'" or are you asking about `paddlea` or are you asking about how to change the speed of the ball? And what does this have to do with your IDE?

Comment: where is the error in the code and what should I replace it with? I got a reply from another user he said 'You're trying to reference paddlea but it is defined as paddle_a so you need to be consistent and  use paddle_a like it is named above.' I am did not understand his reply and therefore asked to locate the error and what should I replace the error with.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reference `paddlea` but it is defined as `paddle_a` so you need to be consistent and use `paddle_a` like it is named above.

As for paddle speed, it looks like the ball speed is controlled here:

```
    #move the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() +ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)
```

So, the position gets modified by `dx` and `dy`, so, modifying those variables where they're set above to

```
ball.dx = 2
ball.dy = 2
```

would adjust the speed of the ball.

Comment: could you please tell me that in which the error is present regarding paddle a. and what should I write instead of it and where

Comment: @VedPawar search and replace `paddlea` -> `paddle_a`